# Why can't I get the data of an entry and use it in a sentence?

Tags: python, tkinter, frameworks, tkinter-entry, data-entry

I did most of the job, but when I enter the variables that I want to calculate, it doesn't work. There is a problem with the function part and below. Can someone please help me?
Thanks

```
from tkinter import * 

win = Tk()
win.title("Age Generator")
win.geometry("600x300")
win.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)

etiket = Label(text="Welcome to the age generator.\nThis app, calculates your age with the year that you will choose",font="Cambria 12",fg="gray",anchor=CENTER)
etiket.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1)

yaz = Label(text="Enter your age:",font="Cambria 10",bg="lightgray")
yaz.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.3)

age = Entry()
age.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.3)

yaz2 = Label(text="Ener the year:",font="Cambria 10",bg="lightgray")
yaz2.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.4)

year = Entry()
year.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.4)


def get_data():
    cf1 = etiket.config(text= age.get(), font= ('Helvetica 13'))
    cf2 = Label.config(text= year.get(), font= ('Helvetica 13'))
    # label= Label(text="", font=('Helvetica 13'))
    # label.pack()
    result = Label(text=f"{year} yılında {cf2 - (2023-cf1)} yaşında olacaksınız!",font="Cambria Bold 10",bg="darkgray",fg="black",anchor=CENTER)
    result.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button = Button(text="Calculate My Age",command=get_data,width=15,height=2)
button.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.5)

mainloop()
```

I was trying to do an application that tells you your age with the year that you choose.
For example assume that I'm 20 and I'm asking which age I will be in 3786. The Machine answers it by the codes that I wrote.

But however, I always get TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cf1` is the result of the call to `config`, not an integer. The same can be said for `cf2`. Because of this, `f"{year} yılında {cf2 - (2023-cf1)` won't work because you're trying to do math on `Label`s instead of numbers.

You can fix this by separating the `get`ting of each value from the `config`uration of `cf1` and `cf2`

```
def get_data():
    age_value = age.get()
    year_value = year.get()

    cf1 = etiket.config(text=age_value, font=('Helvetica 13'))
    cf2 = Label(text=year_value, font=('Helvetica 13'))
    cf2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    result = Label(
        text=f"{year_value} yılında {int(year_value) - (2023 - int(age_value))} yaşında olacaksınız!",
        font="Cambria Bold 10",
        bg="darkgray",
        fg="black", anchor=CENTER
    )
    result.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Comment: Typo error cf2 = Label.config(text=age_value, to cf2 = Label.config(text=year_value,. You could do this etiket.config(text=age_value, font=('Helvetica 13'))
    Label.config(text=year_value, font=('Helvetica 13'))

Comment: @toyotaSupra Fixed! I somehow glossed over the fact that `cf2` wasn't properly instantiated. Good catch.

Comment: I know that too.

Comment: `cf1` is not a label, it is the result of `.config(...)` which is `None`.

Comment: @acw1668 ah you're right! I'll fix the wording

Comment: I also think that `f"{year} ..."` should be `f"{year_value} ..."` instead.